# IIS with VBNet Aspx, how to setup/config a site (programmatically or not) to have a folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, directory

I have IIS, using Aspx with VBNet.

I have a site ex. mystockmarketeg.com

I have many pages of the assets of the market, e.g. I use the ? and cod=THEASSET to change the page I want to display e.g.:

```
mystockmarketeg.com?myinsidepage.aspx?cod=ASSET1
mystockmarketeg.com?myinsidepage.aspx?cod=ASSET2
mystockmarketeg.com?myinsidepage.aspx?cod=ASSET3
```

Just changing the cod parameter I can access different pages.

But I think this doesn't perform very well on google.

So I want to have a url like this:

```
mystockmarketeg.com/ASSET1
mystockmarketeg.com/ASSET2
mystockmarketeg.com/ASSET3
```

Is there a way programatically in ASPX VBNEt or changing some property on ISS to do it without the need to create folders and putting the index page on each folder?

Comment: Yes. If you research "asp.net routing" you will find plenty of documentation for how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx) to achieve this result. Note that if you have hyperlinks with dynamic URLs, the URLs should be generated using `<%$RouteUrl:...parameters...%>`.

See also a [detailed ASP.NET Routing description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).